# Keytool.exe - converting PFX to Java PKCS12 keystore. Unknown certificate?

Tags: java, keystore, keytool

I'm converting a PFX to a Java keystore like so:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\keytool.exe" -importkeystore -srckeystore "C:\Temp\temp.pfx" -srcstoretype pkcs12 -srcstorepass "tempcertpass" -destkeystore "C:\Temp\trusted.certs" -deststoretype PKCS12 -deststorepass "tempstorepass" -destkeypass "tempstorepass"
```

My PFX is explorted with all certificates in the chain, and the key.

The command above generates a trusted.certs file which I then copy over to my system-wide Java configuration location in C:\Windows\Sun\Java\Deployment.

**The Problem**

When I look in the Java control panel and go to the 'Security' tab > 'Manage certificates', my certificate displays as:

Issued To: Unknown Subject

Issued By: Unknown Issuer

However if I change -deststoretype in my command line to JKS, the certificates appear as they should?

I am using JDK 1.8.0_181.  Is this a bug or am I missing something?  Thanks.

Comment: I suppose the original PFX file contains an RSA key pair and the public key is properly signed by another key, is it right?

Comment: Yes - the PFX contains a code signing certificate, an intermediate certificate and a root certificate....

Comment: I've even used KeyStore Explorer (https://keystore-explorer.org/) to create a keystore from scratch by creating a new PKCS12 keystore, Tools > Import Key/Pair > PKCS12 > Import my PFX,  and I've saved that and get exactly the same issue.  I'm wondering if it's a Java security setting or similar for PKCS12?

Comment: Incidentally, the keystore verifies fine (with no errors) when running jarsigner.exe -verify....